# WP8 Emulator cant connect to Internet when connected with a dongle

Tags: windows-phone-8-emulator

I am using a plug and play dongle for internet connection. My WP8 emulator is not working ...I tried all the steps mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_beforestart) and on various other forums.. but it was of no help...I am using a 64 bit machine and Hyper-V is on.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem which even Microsoft is unable to answer as of date.

Windows Phone 8 Emulator has a separate IP of its own, different from the IP of the host computer. It needs a dedicated internet connection for itself.
When you are connecting the dongle, you are feeding internet only to the host system and not to the emulator.

One way to get internet on emulator is to use WLAN connection on the system. You can create a WiFi hotspot and that will provide internet to emulator.

In case, you only have dongle as an option, then you have to do tethering with another system.
Create a peer-to-peer network using a LAN cable with another nearby system and change the IPV4 of all available virtual switch adapters of both the systems to dynamic. (no static IP)

Then use dongle to share internet for both the systems. If the other system successfully gets the internet, be sure that the emulator will also get the internet.

You can google out how to create a peer-to-peer connection.

Happy coding :)